# Database Capsule manager is not working

Tags: ajax, whmcs

My WHMCS version is 7. I have a drop down containing the list of clients. For getting the client list I'm using Capsule manager. On Selecting a client from drop down I have another db queries based on it. For that I added the following js in script.js file.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('#clientList').on('change', function () {
        var clientId = this.value;
        $.ajax({
            url: "/modules/addons/test/test.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {clientId: clientId},
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

in test.php file I added the following code

```
if (isset($_POST['clientId'])) {
    try {
        $clientList = Capsule::table('customtable')
            ->select('*')
            ->get();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $error = "Error: {$e->getMessage()}";
        echo $error;
    }
}
```

Problem is, here on using capsule im getting 500 internal server error. How to access DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `require_once '/var/www/mysite/init.php';` at the top of my test.php file. And now everything works like charm.